Type mismatch: inferred type is Activity? but Context was expected (flutter_stripe_payment)
I have this error with flutter_stripe_payment:
e: C:\Users\martha\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\flutter_stripe_payment-0.0.18\android\src\main\kotlin\com\dormmom\flutter_stripe_payment\FlutterStripePaymentPlugin.kt: (47, 32): Type mismatch: inferred type is Activity? but Context was expected
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':flutter_stripe_payment:compileDebugKotlin'.


A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.compilerRunner.GradleCompilerRunnerWithWorkers$GradleKotlinCompilerWorkAction
Compilation error. See log for more details


Try:


Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Run with --scan to get full insights.


Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 8s
Error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
stripe asked me for a minSdkVersion 21 I added it but I got error type mismatch
